# Spring JPA many to many Json is showing a wrong data format

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am tying to create an API that has many to many relationship.

The JSON I am trying to out put is the following.

```
    [
    {
        "id": 12,
        "firstname": "asdfghjkl ",
        "surname": "asda",
        "techniqueSet": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "techniqueName": "java",
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "techniqueName": "C#",
                
                    }
                ]
     },
            
    {
        "id": 49,
        "firstname": "asc",
        "surname": "as",
        "techniqueSet": []
    },
    {
        "id": 90,
        "firstname": "JACOB",
        "surname": "LOL",
        "techniqueSet": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "techniqueName": "Python",
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "techniqueName": "Haskell",
                
                    }
                ]
    },
    {
        "id": 92,
        "firstname": "Omar",
        "surname": "LOL",
        "techniqueSet": []
    }
]
```

However, I am getting the following.

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "firstname": "asdfghjkl ",
        "surname": "asda",
        "techniqueSet": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "techniqueName": "Java",
                "playersSet": [
                    12
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "techniqueName": "C#",
                "playersSet": [
                    12,
                    {
                        "id": 90,
                        "firstname": "Jacob",
                        "surname": "LOL",
                        "techniqueSet": [
                            1,
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "techniqueName": "Python",
                                "playersSet": [
                                    12,
                                    90
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "techniqueName": "Haskell",
                                "playersSet": [
                                    90
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 49,
        "firstname": "asc",
        "surname": "as",
        "techniqueSet": []
    },
    {
        "id": 90,
        "firstname": "LOL",
        "surname": "LOL",
        "techniqueSet": []
    },
    91,
    {
        "id": 92,
        "firstname": "Omar",
        "surname": "LOL",
        "techniqueSet": []
    }
]
```

My Java following are the entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "players")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Players {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="player_id")
    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String surname;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "able_to_use",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "player_id", referencedColumnName = "player_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "technique_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private List<Technique> techniqueSet ;
    //Getters and setters
```

My second entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "technique")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Technique {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "technique_name")
    private String techniqueName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "techniqueSet", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Players> playersSet ;

    //Getters and Setter
```

Can you please help? I am new to the JPA framework. I think the error might be the way the join is referenced in each entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `playersSet` property in `Technique` class either `transient` or use `@JsonIgnore`.

What's happening here is recursive serialization. First Player is being serialize, then it gets to Technique class, but Technique class also has players in its field. So that will be serialize as well (again).

For more info about Jackson annotation read this [simple intro](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)

For more info about transient in Java read this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transient-keyword-java/)

Comment: the problem i am facing now. it seems that the if the technique set already has the value, it will not print the JSON again if lets say another Player needs the same value. Do you know how to fix this?